# Ruby on Rails what does this hash output mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, hashmap

```
#<Hashie::Mash created_time="1366084479" from=#<Hashie::Mash 
full_name="alyssabri_" id="24110592" username="ally"> id="4350706" 
text="Some Text">
```

What does this mean? I get it when I do this:

```
    <% (@arr).each do |media| %>
        <%= media.caption %>
    <% end %>
```

I'm trying to get the `text` which is in `caption`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is telling you that `media.caption` is an instance of `Hashie::Mash` (a gem you have installed in your application provides `Hashie`, similar to Ruby's native `Hash`). You need to get the `text` key/value pair from that `Hashie` instance

```
<% (@arr).each do |media| %>
    <%= media.caption.text %>
<% end %>
```

---

To answer your question about how to gracefully bypass those `media` instances with no related `caption`, you can do something like this

```
<% (@arr).each do |media| %>
    <%= media.caption.text unless media.caption.blank? %>
<% end %>
```

or filter out those `caption`-less `media` objects up front

```
<% @arr.select{ |m| m.caption.present? }.each do |media| %>
    <%= media.caption.text %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried doing `media.caption.text` but I get an error `undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: That means that `caption` is `Nil` and not what you pasted in the top of your Question.

Comment: well it is going through a large amount of data, and i'm outputting what I can see... Maybe some data shows nil while its iterating? How do I bypass it and output if its not nil? Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer to show you two alternatives to avoid the blank `caption` associations.